# CSS3 Transforms Operating Differently Between Browsers

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, 3d, safari

I'm currently experimenting 3D Transforms with CSS3. I'm aware not every browser currently supports 3D Transforms, however, I'm noticing marked differences in placement of elements between browsers. In Safari, the element lines up perfectly where I'd expect it to. But in Chrome, the element is a couple of 100 pixels off.

I can't find any information on the web corroborating, but after some investigation, it seems that in Safari, the X-Axis origin is on the left most side of the window, and in Firefox and Chrome, the X-Axis lies dead-center on the window (FYI, the Y and Z-axes have the same origin between these three browsers.

Any ideas on how to rectify this?

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
#container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-perspective: 1200px;
  -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}

#cube {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(438px,137px,-282px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: 3d-perspective;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(438px,137px,-282px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  -moz-transform-style: 3d-perspective;
}
```

Comment: Is JavaScript an option?

Comment: Might be scss compass or less can unify this behavior ?

Comment: Justin, Have been using JavaScript, and would be willing to use JavaScript to solve this. I have considered checking for which browser is being used, and setting CSS accordingly, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

Alright...

I figured it out after a few hours of tinkering, and wanted to post my answer because this information may help someone else.

What was happening was that in a div that #cube was within (let's call it #wrapper), I had the css property "text-align" set to centered. In Firefox and Chrome, that setting set the origin of the Y-Axis to the center of the screen (i.e., the center of #wrapper, since #wrapper is the width of the screen.) However, Safari does not take that property into its calculations of 3D Transforms (possibly 2D transforms as well, though I won't definitively say.) All I had to do was remove that property- and presto!

Comment: I've been baffled by some discrepancies between Safari and Chrome too. Thanks for sharing the solution (and it's good etiquette too).